# rails where query in multiple table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

I have a form which has fields from around three tables, and user can fill in any field and they can make a search.

For example i have these table and columns

> Vehicle:
>
> - rego_num
> - make
> - model
> - vin
> - engine_num
> - transmission, ...
>
> Customer:
>
> - name
> - surname
> - email_address
>
> Address:
>
> - address1
> - address2
> - address3
> - phone
> - work_num
> - primary_num
> - fax

```
Vehicle belongs_to Customer
Customer has_one address
```

User can make search in any of the above mentioned fields, for ex they can enter rego alone and find serch or rego with make and model or name alone or with phone,

they can enter partial phone number and it should find it, phone is integer column.

I thought of finding vehicle column, if vehicle exist and then find customer, but the problem is they can enter customer fields alone.

I think i can write a joins and do a where query, like

```
vehicle.joins(:customer)
```

but address is related to vehicle, Can anyone suggest me how to send params to search method and write a query to find records

I checked pg_search gem it has one keyword to search against multiple columns, but i have multiple value to search against the particular column.

Comment: Maybe this gem will be helpful: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack It lets you search through a model and its associations easily, you can have a single form field search through all attributes at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to send parameters, and in controller you need to create a query with sql.

eg:

get the all params into loacal variables or you can use directly.

```
reg_no = params[:reg_no]
make = params[:make]
query = 'where '

if reg_no.present?
 query = query+ "reg_no ilike #{reg_no} AND "
if make.present?
 query = query + "make ilike #{make} AND "
```

use "=" is user enters "entire string" if it is partial use "ilike".

now you can use join and use the where condition.